# Phonegap npm install not working due to ant

Tags: node.js, cordova, ant, npm

I am currently having an issue installing phonegap 3.5 via npm on my windows 8.1 OS.
I already installed and set my path as seen in this image
    http://i653.photobucket.com/albums/uu260/tidus_david/path.png

I already installed ANT, JDK and Android SDK as seen in this image 
    http://i653.photobucket.com/albums/uu260/tidus_david/Error.png

and finally when I try to npm install -g phonegap I always get the error shown in the image
    http://i653.photobucket.com/albums/uu260/tidus_david/npminstallerror.png

I tried removing the npm modules folder from %APPDATA%, also I tried to npm cache clear without results. What is happening? I tried for days to install it without success, here I attach my log https://mega.co.nz/#!X8BWxQyD!Ikn9wMdjnsGuFlZSqNwxpSPI92MNyzw95P4qMbL4BuQ

Also I tried out to install cordova, and it installs but when I try to cordova add android platform it fails and says that ant is not installed 
I have ant installed, I already search all over google and stackoverflow for answers about this issue, I am totally sure that my path is ok and that ant is installed because it returns the version when I write in the cmd ant -version 
Also the cmd I am using haves Admin privileges.
I tried to install phonegap version 3.4 and it installed but when I tried to compile it shows ant error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please attach the ant error log that you are talking about.

Comment: jitendra, here is the ant error when I execute cordova platform add android "i653.photobucket.com/albums/uu260/tidus_david/anterror.png"

Comment: also I attach the ant error when I execute phonegap version 3.4 using the command phonegap build android "i653.photobucket.com/albums/uu260/tidus_david/phonegapanterror.png"

Comment: can you please show us the contents of your path? This is almost definitely a path issue.

Comment: @Lorenzo the contents of my path are on this image http://i653.photobucket.com/albums/uu260/tidus_david/path.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going through your screenshots and error log. Everything looks fine and your PATH has been properly defined, and as you said, ANT can print its -version number when queried so it's definitely not a problem with ANT

It looks like a problem with npm, if you have NodeJS, you will need to upgrade npm by downloading the latest NodeJS package (you might want to perform a clean install to be on the safe side).

http://nodejs.org/download/

Comment: It was a problem with environment variables of the nodejs, I added to my PATH the nodejs install directory and I added the %AppData%\Roaming\npm and everything is working now, thanks

Comment: Glad you sorted it out and thanks for posting back your solution.